# Deploy changes from bitbucket using ANT Migration Tool

Tags: ant, jenkins, ci

I'm starting to implement Continuous Integration and I'm using Bitbucket, Jenkins and the ANT Migration Tool provided by Salesforce.

I want to deploy from a Dev Sandbox environment to a Dev-Integration env, but I want to deploy only the changes that I did and not all code that is into src folder (all salesforce metadata). There's a way to only deploy that changes ( obviously keeping in mind test classes and dependences)? or what would be the best approach.

Thanks,

Comment: If you don't need it to be entirely automated then the company I work for (https://gearset.com) might be worth checking out. I won't put this as an answer though as it doesn't match your needs of totally automated, although watch this space :)

Comment: Flosum provides a ready-made out of the box continuous integration solution. The solution is 100% native salesforce, there is nothing to install or configure after you have registered the organizations.

Answer (score 5):

We are using a very similar setup internally. What we have found works is that

1) All devs work in their own separate sandboxes.

2) All development is done in feature branches.

3) When work is ready for QA/Integration testing feature branches are merged into master.

4) Jenkins build runs whenever there is a commit to master and performs a deploy to the QA/Integration environment.

You may want to check out the Atlassian [Guide for Setting up CI](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/SFDC/Setting+Up+Continuous+Integration+and+Deployment). They use Bamboo but most of the issues you will run into with maintaining your package.xml and keeping config changes in sync will be very similar.

Answer (score 3):

The description and detailed setup provided in the below link is very useful and it worked in my case.
May be it helps you : [Continuous Integration](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/continuous-integration-in-salesforce-using-jenkins-and-git-video-tutorial/)